# Newbie to Python syntax - Error - suspect use of single/double quotes

Tags: python

This is my first time using Python and I am receiving the attached message when attempting to run a script.

here is the code (line 32 is the line starting "font-size:...":

```
# County style
'font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1;
stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;
marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'
```

Could any helpful person tell me whats up here?[image]

Comment: please post the rest of the code before "font-size"

Comment: anyway, it seems like you're trying to create a string without the quotes...

Comment: According to the traceback, line 32 begins `path_style = ...`, but that is not what you showed above.  Show the actual line, with a couple lines before and after for context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a multiline string, you need triple quotes (`'''` or `"""`). Example:

```
'''font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1;
stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;
marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'''
```